# How to render a section from partial view into the layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, rendering, sitecore, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to generate metatags in a partial rendering. Problem is that I cannot render a section. I have tried various suggestions provided on net. Below is the scenario.

_Layout.cshtml

```
@RenderBody()
```

- Renders body apart from some partial rendering

MainView.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/News/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

- Has partial renderings

Display.cshtml
- Has some partial renderings and HTML inside
- Also contains code for metadata that I require to make available in the _Layout

Below is what I have tried:
Scenario 1:
Display.cshtml

```
{
@section main
{...}
}
```

MainView.cshtml

```
{
@section main
{
@RenderSection("main", false)
}
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
{
@RenderSection("main", false)
}
```

Result: MainView throws exception... asp.net mvc cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method.

Scenario 2:
- Tried to exchange data between views using ViewBag.

```
@ViewBag.PropertyName = "test value";
```

Result: No value in @ViewBag.PropertyName

Scenario 3: (This was frustrating)
- _Layout.cshtml

```
@section main
{
<div>this is it!!</div>
}
```

@RenderSection("main", false);

Result: Error..... Section "main" is not defined.

I did not had a very good understanding of views/partial views (very generic) before I started on this issue. Working on this, I learnt a bit further about 
@RenderPage()
@RenderSection()
and ofcourse
@Html.Partial()

Nothing basic that I have looked through has worked for me so far. Is there anything I am missing out on? Or is there any detail of the parent/child relationships between the views that I have misunderstood?

Any pointers towards a right direction would greatly help. :)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

*You seem to have unneeded braces all over the place in the examples. You also use the term PartialView when you are using layouts, which means they are views, not partial views. A PartialView does not have a layout/master page*

To add a new section to a *master page/layout*, that can be provided by any *view*, you just need

### In  _Layout.cshtml master page:

```
@RenderSection("main", false)
```

### and add *main* section in a MainView.cshtml view:

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/3News/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>Your page content that gets rendered by RenderBody() as it is not in a section</div>

@section main
{
   <div>Some content to render inside the layout's main section</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry about the braces. I was trying to give an idea of what each of the .cshtml file contains. It would be worth mentioning that I am using Sitecore CMS which has its own rendering model layer. MainView uses their Rendering Model. Also, further digging into the issue, I came across a post that suggested that their Rendering model does not allows section rendering. I guess, I will have to dive deeper into their rendering model to "workaround" the issue. Your solution above makes perfect sense and I have been trying to do the same since last 2 days. Thx for the post. :)

Comment: Ah. That puts a different light on it. Always worth mentioning a CMS in the tags. I will adjust them now.

Answer (score 0):

To the problem above, I had a workaround in my situation but it is not serving the purpose. Anyways, I will share how I was able to RenderSection finally.

```
New rendering: Tags.cshtml
<tags>

MainView.cshtml
@section tags
{
 @Html.Partial("Tags.cshtml")
}

_Layout.cshtml
@RenderSection("tags")
```

This rendered the tags fine.

Now, I cannot share the variables that helps me to construct the tags which reside in Display.cshtml.

Thanks for reading through :)